# Firebase emulator - provide custom name/path to runtimeconfig.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Is there a way to provide .runtimeconfig.json location though a command line? Can't find any info on that.

Something like below?

```
firebase emulators:start --runtimeconfig ./path/to/.runtimeconfig-prod.json
```

I have two runtimeconfig.json: one for development and another for production and I'm looking for an easy way to switch emulator environment.

Note: my dev and prod applications are stored under two separate firebase projects.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [lilalinux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410212/lilalinux) said, you can set `CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG` with the path of your config file.

This is how I did it.

I created configurations for two environments (`staging` and `prod`) inside `functions/emulator-tests/config`.
This is part of my project structure.

```
functions
  emulator-tests
    config
      .runtimeconfig.staging.json // config for staging env
      .runtimeconfig.prod.json // config for prod env
  src
  .runtimeconfig.json // default config I had
  package.json
```

I installed [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and added two scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "emulate-staging": "cross-env CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG=./emulator- tests/config/.runtimeconfig.staging.json firebase emulators:start",
  "emulate-prod": "cross-env CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG=./emulator-tests/config/.runtimeconfig.prod.json firebase emulators:start"
  ...
}
```

Then, from inside the `functions` folder I can emulate using any of those two environment configurations by running the respective script: `npm run emulate-staging` or `npm run emulate-prod`

Source:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/629

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path and name via `CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG`, e.g.:
`CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG="../../.runtimeconfig.json" firebase emulators:start`

The path can be absolute or relative to the location where it would be expected as default.

Comment: do you have an example executing it as an npm script? So far I can't really make it work. In my package.json I put a script like "emulator-dev":"CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG='./functions/.runtimeconfig-dev.json' firebase emulators:start". And then execute it with "npm run emulator-dev" but as the result the config variables are not loaded.

Comment: "serve-functions": "pushd projects/my-functions && ../../node_modules/.bin/tsc && popd && CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG='../../.runtimeconfig.json' firebase emulators:start --only functions --project=default"